# How to improve Website Waiting time?

Tags: yslow, pagespeed, speed-test

While website loading speed testing I found that website is sometimes loading very quickly and some times it takes lot of time to start loading. When I checked it in detail, I found on some requests wait time was just in few hundred milliseconds, while on some other request which was slow it was actually taking 5 to 30 seconds in wait time.

What may be the cause of this kind of deviation from few milliseconds to 30 or more seconds. And how to improve it.

The site is build upon ASP.net MVC3 and Microsoft SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What patterns are there i.e. are the same URLs always slow, and other URLs always fast, or does it just appear to be random?

Look at what else is running on the server, is it a dedicated server or a VPS?

Look at the DB performance i.e. is it consistent, which are the queries that are taking the longest time, most CPU, most IO etc.

How busy is the site, do the slowdowns match when the app-pool is being recycled or started up?

Comment: All urls are fast/slow randomly. Its a dedicated server.

As per your suggestions, we have monitored it, and found that it was usually slow when SQL is busy and taking high CPU.

Yes, the first request is usually the slowest one.

But, this happens with the static html page too, don't know why?

Comment: The steps you suggested are the ways to find the bottlenecks into the application. Actually the site was doing some operation in the back-end even if for static resources. So we just excluded static resources where required and it improved the performance in general.